# I cannot get push notifications to work with ARCGIS after deleting and recreating certificates many times

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, arcgis, esri

I have spent hours deleting certificates and remaking them. I've followed this tutorial https://developers.arcgis.com/en/geotrigger-service/guide/ios-push-notifications/ many times and I still cannot get push notifications to work. I was using the geoloqi.com API but they were bought by esri and just released a new api. I had push working with geoloqi.

The only thing questionable about that tutorial is where it says "Paste the pem file in the box" I just copied from finder and pasted it like it said but it's weird because usually there's a browse for file button and then you upload. I don't know, thats probably not the problem but I thought I'd bring it up.

With this test code:

```
[[AGSGTApiClient sharedClient] postPath:@"device/notify"
                                 parameters:@{@"text": @"Push notifications are working!", @"url": @"http://developers.esri.com"}
                                    success:^(id res) {
                                        NSLog(@"device/notify success: %@", res);
                                    }
                                    failure:^(NSError *err) {
                                        NSLog(@"device/notify failure: %@", err.userInfo);
                                    }];
```

I get:

```
device/notify success: {
    devices =     {
        TKhqTzrTSQI0DGBa = queued;
    };
```

But I never receive the push. Does anybody have a suggestion I can try next because I am lost?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you'll want to check is whether you have the proper certificates configured for your application. The best way to do this is completely outside the Geotrigger API so that it's not adding more steps to the mix. There are any number of ways you can do this, but we have also written a guide you can follow here: https://github.com/Esri/pushlet/tree/master/client

If you are familiar with Node.js, you can run the Pushlet server yourself and send test notifications to your device. If you are not familiar with Node.js, you can follow the first two steps, [Set up the Certificates](https://github.com/Esri/pushlet/tree/master/client#set-up-the-certificates) and [Test the Connection](https://github.com/Esri/pushlet/tree/master/client#test-the-connection).

Once you have verified you are not getting any SSL errors communicating with APNS, and you have verified you can use the certificates to send a push notification to your device directly, if you're still having trouble with sending a push notification through the Geotrigger API, you can contact our support at geotrigger-support@esri.com.